# UITextView not loading/showing the large text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have a simple UITextView in my login screen where I need to display Terms & conditions.I have a very large text in Terms and Conditions.In the interface builder I have added text to the UITextView. In the interface builder the text is getting showed properly. But when I run the application the UITextView is empty. If I give small text in the UItextView it is rendering properly but huge/large text is not getting displayed.

---

Here is the code.

```
- (IBAction)showTermsOfUse:(id)sender{
    termsOfUseText.text = @"/***/";
    termsOfUseText.scrollEnabled = YES;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; // begins animation block
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];        // sets animation duration
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    termsOfUse.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,416);
    [UIView commitAnimations];   // commits the animation block.  This Block is done.
}
```

Comment: Is it getting truncated or scrolled up?

Comment: Enabled the scrolling of textview

Comment: it is not at all displaying/showing the text. yes.. scrolling is enabled.

Comment: Have you connected the outlet ? :p

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I have given the text in interface builder only, so no need to connect it to any outlet rite?

Comment: yes... thats why a smiley... just to confirm, if you missed.

Comment: Reset your simulator and then try

Comment: Actually My text view should be non editable, it should show only the text which I gave in the interface builder. But if I make my TextView editable and user interation enabled, when the simulator launches my screen and if I tap on the text view the key board is coming up and at that time it showing my large text in the text view automatically.Strage behavior of UITextView.......

Comment: u can set the text in code and keep editing false.

Comment: May be UITextView is loaded before text being showed and after you click it shows the text. We need code for further clarification.

Comment: If I add the text through code, It is showing the text but it is not getting scrolled.I have set scrollEnabled to YES also.below is the code.

Comment: If you set `delaysContentTouches` to `NO` you will hopefully find your text view now working (i mean scroll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had faced the same problem and i solved it my taking IBOutlet of UITextView and setting the value in the code like this

```
UITextView *txtView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
[txtView setText:@"Your long text"];
[txtView setEditable:NO];
[self.view addSubview:txtView];
[txtView release];
```

Another option can be take a webview and load your contents in webview.

Comment: Adding through code is working fine with me. How you have added can you show ur code.

Comment: in your above answer.. if we make textview user interation editable it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create this `UITextView` programmatically

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(AsYouNeed)];
[textView  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:YourSize]];
textView.text = @"test my font size";
[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];  
[self.view addSubview:textView];
[textView release];
```

Comment: he wants a textView not textfeild

Comment: @Dhara - sory for that ..i changed :)

Comment: `[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];` that solve your problem for scroll :)

Answer (score 0):

By giving the text programmatically....and

```
termsofUseText.text =   @"MY LARGE TEXT GOES HERE......    "
termsOfUseText.scrollEnabled = YES;
termsOfUseText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
termsOfUseText.editable = NO;
```