# UITextView not showing long text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

My iOS app is not showing long attributed strings. I have a cell in a tableview which contains this textView. When the text is very long the tableview is unresponsive for a while but when it loads the text is not shown. All other cells are displayed fine. And the textView works fine with small text strings.

Here's the code:

```
            descriptionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellAdDetailDescription"];
            descriptionCell.bodyTextView.delegate = self;
            NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.ad.body];

            UIFont *cellFont;
            cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0];

            NSDictionary *attributesDictionary;
            NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10;

            attributesDictionary = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle , NSFontAttributeName: cellFont};

            [str addAttributes:attributesDictionary range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
            descriptionCell.bodyTextView.attributedText = str;
```

I pasted the long string [here](http://pastebin.com/mUPUaGVS). I debugged and `str` is being loaded fine containing the desired text.

Whats wrong here?
What is the max allowed string length in `UITextView`?

**EDIT:** very odd, when trying selection in the textView, the text is being shown in the magnifying glass. I posted a video [here](http://youtu.be/hrExfbEeSSU).

Is it a bug in UITextView?

Here is the screenshot. The blank white at the bottom is the textView.
[image: here is the screenshot]

Comment: Please paste a snapshot of how it is being rendered currently

Comment: Its showing a blank view. The height seems to be adjusting accordingly but is not showing the text. Uploading snap shots...

Comment: Your code works fine when I simply create a textView and add it to a normal view - I would add NSLog(@"textView: %@", descriptionCell.bodyTextView); after you dequeue the cell. I would be willing to bet it's either nil or the frame is incorrect, like it has a 0 height or something. https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlucia4wguc8mji/Screenshot%202014-07-15%2017.29.32.png https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9duiyptzlva5di/Screenshot%202014-07-15%2017.29.47.png

Comment: @Mike plz see the edit and watch the video.

Comment: @Mike your example's text is not as long as mine. Plz copy the text from here: http://pastebin.com/mUPUaGVS

Comment: The length doesn't matter - I'm quiet confident this isn't a bug in UITextView. This video shows that the length doesn't matter. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zt0whns8deiqak/video.mov Did you put the log statement in like I said?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create the textView?

Comment: @Mike the textView is loaded in storyboard. I have a UITableViewCell and it contains the textView as subview. I am adjusting the height programmatically. Did you watch my video? http://youtu.be/hrExfbEeSSU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57353/discussion-between-mike-and-abdullah-umer).

Comment: @Mike very odd but setting scroll enabled fixes the issue.

Comment: hi @AbdullahUmer, I have same issues when rendering large text in textView have u find any solution.

Comment: @DhavalPatel it was probably a bug in the iOS. I don't see the issue now in newer updates. However, disabling scroll and then enabling again had fixed the issue and text would show up.

Comment: Thanks @AbdullahUmer i finally solve figure out my issues

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could have something to do with the scrolling. If you are showing all the text (i.e. the text view is expanded to be as high as it needs to be, and so is the table view cell), the scrolling is done by the table view. If the text view is smaller, you have to scroll to see all the text - this might cause a conflict with the table view, which is also a scroll view.

It has been suggested that you disable the scrolling of the text view before adding the attributed text and reenable it afterwards. If you are showing the whole text in the table view, you can leave the text view scrolling disabled. In some cases, it will only work if scrolling is enabled. You should check this possibility as well.

Comment: I don't want the textView to be scrollable. The textVIew is autoresizable and it fits the text. I adjust the cell height according to text.

Comment: I disabled scrolling and it has no effect.

Comment: how odd.. setting scroll enabled fixes the issue.

Comment: So I was generally on the right track. You should accept this answer.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue (= very long attributed text didn't show up in the UITextView within an autosized UITableViewCell). I tried all accepted answers from here and from this question: [UITextView not loading/showing the large text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436771/uitextview-not-loading-showing-the-large-text). None did work.

However I then found out that - in my case - it just works fine on the device. So if you're still struggling with this kind of problem, don't rely on the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you UITextView not show all text because it Frame is too small so it truncates the text to fit with its frame. you can do follow step to show all text:

- In your CustomUITableCell, override layoutSubView:

Use this function to calculate size of TextView that fit it content
[textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height

After that, calculate and set new frame for TExtView (in uitableCell custom)

- In the tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath, calculate new size of textView (also height of cell) similar like above and return right height for cell.